# USB device not accepting address 5, error -71

Tags: usb

I had problem with my ubuntu 14.04. Today Ive started it and it was without top and side panel, so I have found some tips, how to fix it. Nothing helped me, because I didnt found Unity, so Ive restarted pc, turned it on and terminal started with "USB device not accepting address 5, error -71".
So now i dont see anything, just terminal and if I try `Ctrl + Alt + F7`, I see only that error.

Now I really dont know, what to do. Unplugged all USB, restarted and still same problem.